Defining common behaviour for antlr4 visit methods
I have an antlr4 grammar with dozens of rules. There's code I want to run as the Visitor enters each node, i.e. shared behaviour across all node types. For example, I might have a grammar like this...
lost : jack | kate;
jack : 'JACK';
kate : 'KATE';

...and a visitor like this (I'm using antlr4ts, so the generated code is in TypeScript)...
export default class MyVisitor extends VisitorInterface {
    sharedBehaviour(ctx: ParseNode) {
        // ...
    }
    visitLost(ctx: LostContext) {
         this.sharedBehaviour(ctx);
         // ...
    }
    visitJack(ctx: JackContext) {
         this.sharedBehaviour(ctx);
         // ...
    }
    visitKate(ctx: KateContext) {
         this.sharedBehaviour(ctx);
         // ...
    }
}

How can I replicate this without copy/pasting this.sharedBehaviour(ctx) into every single visitX method?
Based on the docs, I thought I could maybe define a custom superclass for all the parse nodes, and in the accept(...) method of my custom parse node, I could call visitor.sharedBehaviour(...). But I'm not sure how to add this sharedBehaviour(...) method to the antlr-generated visitor interface (which I called VisitorInterface above), so that it's visible to the parse nodes. Also, I'd prefer to avoid messing with the code generation, and I thought there'd be an easier way to do this.

I'm using antlr4ts, so the generated code is in TypeScript. Not sure why you are using the 4 year old antlr4ts fork because both the official Antlr4 tool and Mike's Antlr4ng generate .ts files for the visitor via the -visitor option. For "sharedBehavior()", why not define a visit() or visitChildren() with the code you want to execute for every PT node?


I just started working on this codebase, there hasn't been time to migrate from antlr4ts. 2. I tried defining visit(), but it never gets called. The default implementation of visitChildren calls child.accept(visitor) with each child node rather than visitor.visit(child), and the child node then calls visitor.visitThisTypeOfNode(this). Seems a bit hacky to hook into visitChildren, but I guess I can try that, thanks!


One possible solution I've come up with: implement visit() in your visitor with the shared behaviour (don't forget the call to super.visit(node)), and implement visitChildren() so that it does this.visit(child) for each child node, as opposed to the default implementation, which does child.accept(this). Then you have to make sure that you're not using node.accept(visitor) anywhere, since that would bypass your hook.
